# How to compare values of the same column and return true/false?

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean

I am trying to build a query that will compare the last two values of a specific column and will return true if the number has risen or false if it's lower.

How can I achieve that with MS SQL?

The data looks like this

Tickets:

71

72

73

74

75

So say I want to take the latest two and compare them and then return a boolean value. is it achievable?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "latest" unless you have a column that specifies that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to fetch each one individually and compare:

```
select (case when last_but_one.ticket < last_one.ticket then 'less than'
             when last_but_one.ticket = last_one.ticket then 'equal'
             when last_but_one.ticket > last_one.ticket then 'greater than'
        end)
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by ord desc
      offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only
     ) last_one cross join
     (select t.*
      from t
      order by ord desc
      offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only
     ) last_but_one;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0f78ad896bb16dc278d2a9e0eaa49f3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: So i have a column that specifies Datetime which is called DateTime. but when trying to run your query i have got errors. 
```Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'fetch'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 13

Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement.
```

Comment: @MightySwami . . . I fixed the errors and added a fiddle.

Comment: @MightySwami, add `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements with sample data to your question if you want a worked solution. Otherwise, answers can only guess.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! by making some adjustments I was able to customize this to my usage.